# spring mvc prefix text to all urls

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to add the following prefix to all my urls

/login should now be /springmvc/login

What are the changes that needs to be made. I add the following but no use. I also tried a updating all of the following no luck, sometime the login page works but the result page which is mostly return "login" does not work

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
    <property name="pathPrefix" value="springmvc" />
    <property name="caseSensitive" value="false" />
</bean>
```

I have updated my controller as follows

```
@RequestMapping("/springmvc")
public class LoginController {
```

my web.xml is as follows, I havn't updated those

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

my spring security related code is as follows

```
<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? /springmvc isn't the context root is it?

Comment: it isn't the context root. so if my app is called ui, the url needs to be localhost/ui/springmvc/login, right now localhost/ui/login works but i want to add springmvc

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding '/springmvc' to the mapping for your dispatcher servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/springmvc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That should give you a common prefix for your controllers. You may have to tweak spring security separately to get the login/logout links working. E.G.

```
<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/springmvc//welcome*" access="ADMIN" />
    <form-login login-page="/springmvc/login" default-target-url="/springmvc/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/springmvc/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/springmvc/logout" />
</http>
```

The ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping class is for setting up "convention over configuration" mappings. In other words the path is derived from the class/package name which means you don't need the @RequestMapping annotation at all.

Comment: does that mean that my LoginController should be in the following package com.xyz.springmvc.LoginController. springmvc preceding the LoginController

Comment: If you choose to use ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping then I think that's the general idea.